# Why assigning an element to unsized array change the assigned element in c?

Tags: c

Well I was trying to assign some element of an array to another array when I noticed that not specifying the size in the latter, somehow modify the content of the former

for example in the following code

```
char buffer[255]; 
char c[] = { buffer[0] };
c[1] = ***
```

when I try to `printf` the `buffer[0]` before assigning c[1] to some arbitrary value
`buffer[0]` holds it's real value But after assigning c[1], Now buffer[0] holds the value of c[1] which is not what I intended at all.

the problem is solved when I specified a size for the c array but anyway I want ask **why** this happened in the first place and if someone can provide some references on such a thing for further reading or something would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array `c[]` has a length of 1 `char` because when you declared it you assigned `{ buffer [0] }` which is an initializer with only 1 value.

Accessing `c[1]` is undefined behavior - element `c[1]` is the second element of the array `c` which only has 1 element - you're assigning to the second element, beyond the bounds of the `c` array, which only has one element.

Comment: So It just overwrites the first element instead of returning an error or something ?

Comment: C does not catch errors like that: it is up to the programmer to know how many elements there are. Only the *system* will catch it if you break something you are not allowed to touch, and the system does not care if you are corrupting something you own.

Comment: @MahmoudSalah no one knows what is going to happen when you try to access memory out of bounds. That is undefined behavior. There's a fair assumption to make here though - due to stack alignment `buffer` begins *right after* `c`. So what you are referring to as `c[1]` (which is out of bounds for `c`) is actually `buffer[0]` in the stack. Don't rely on this though.